# UI is not Updated until I touch the screen in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

In my ios app i am using GCD calls to download some data in background threads , but its not updating UI instantly, I should touch the screen to update UI , following is my code, shall I know why table view is not reloaded though I am trying to Update in Main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //background processing goes here
         // Downloading JSON data from Web APIs
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //update UI here

                //Reloading my table view
                 [objTableView reloadData];
        });
});
```

I have also tried  `runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking` instead of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` but its of no use

```
void runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(void (^block)(void))
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        block();
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual code for `reloading my table view` and `//update UI Here` please share all relevant code

Comment: Is method `reload` is your own method? `UITableView` contains only     `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: @Szu  ,,its reloadData only

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661031/how-to-reload-a-uitableview-while-i-am-looking-at-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348132/reload-data-of-uitableview-in-background All these answers are basically saying you should be doing just `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.objTableView reloadData]; });` Have you set your tableView up correctly with the dataSource and delegate?

Comment: does `objTableView` is not nil?

Comment: can you please try "__block UITableView *tableView = objTableView;" before going into blocks?

Comment: So basically change `[objTableView reload];` to `[objTableView reloadData]` because according the Apple documentation there is no `reload` it's `reloadData` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW61

Comment: please show, how do you update UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer given before user decided to change the questions code**

According to the [Apple Documentation for `UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW61) there is no method called `reload` it should be `reloadData`. So you need to change the line `[objTableView reload];` to `[objTableView reloadData];` as per the [Apple Documentation around `UITableView reloadData:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData). Also if you checkout [How to Reload a UITableView While I am Looking at It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661031/how-to-reload-a-uitableview-while-i-am-looking-at-it) and [Reload data of UITableView in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348132/reload-data-of-uitableview-in-background) these also say it's `[objTableView reloadData];`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
yourtableviewdelegate.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after the reload of the tableview.

Comment: ops... you're coding in Objective C, so you shoud try with [objTableView layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: Thanks for your reply,, I have tried this but no luck

Comment: That's strange...  are you sure objTableView  is not nil?